# Grabbing Values from a JSON API Responce, putting them into webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

Today I have a question that may seem kinda simple the the rest of you. I'm just now learning how to use APIs/JSONs and I'm a little confused. I'm trying to simply grab the temperature from this openweathermap.org API response and displaying it in an html tag.

The javascript from what I know is grabbing the temperature and setting it as a var. I'm confused why I cannot use id="" to set text inside a tag. The code below is what I have so far. I thank you for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var weather;
var temp;
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98&units=metric",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(weather){
    var temp = weather.main.temp;
}
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="temp"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have syntax issues in the script... missing `})` at the end of the script

Comment: `$('#temp').html(temp);` to display the value in the `p` in the success handler

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ArunPJohny have already identified the errors: 1) missing `})` and 2) use `$('#temp')` to get the HTML element. Also you don't need to declare `weather` because it is declared as an argument.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98&units=metric",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(weather) {
      $('#temp').text(weather.main.temp);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<p id="temp"></p>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I can now end the day happily! I'm glad to see I wasn't super duper far off